# How do I get and print a variable stored in localStorage with a POST request?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, flask

In an application in Flask, I need to take a user data from a form to store it with the "localStorage" function and print it on a new page after a POST request allowing to keep the printed name even if the page restarts. I have this code:

**index.html:**

```
<body>
<form id="registro" action="{{ url_for('chatroom') }}" method="post">
        Ingresa al chat <br/>
        <p><input type="text" id="usuario" name="usuario" placeholder="Usuario">
        </p>        
        <input type="submit" id="guardar" value="Enviar" /><br>     
        </form>
</body>
```

**Function in Python/Flask:**

```
@app.route("/chatroom", methods=["POST"])
def chatroom():

    Usuario = request.form.get("usuario")    
    return render_template("chatroom3A.html", Usuario=Usuario)
```

**chatroom3A.html**

```
<body>
…………………………..
<div>Bienvenid@ <label type="text" id="bienvenido"></label></div>
…………………………….
</body>
```

**Code in Javascript:**

```
if (localStorage.getItem('userlog')) {
      const TheUserlog = localStorage.getItem('userlog');
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    

    document.querySelector('#registro').onsubmit = () => {

        // Initialize new request
        const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        const nombre = document.querySelector('#usuario').value;
        
        localStorage.setItem("userlog", nombre);
        
        document.getElementById("usuario").value = "";
        
        request.open('POST', '/chatroom');
        
        const data = new FormData();
        data.append('usuario', usuario);

        // Send request
        request.send(data);

        // Callback function for when request completes
        request.onload = () => {
            
            const TheUserlog = localStorage.getItem('userlog');
            
            if (request.status == 200) {
                
                document.querySelector('#bienvenido').innerHTML = TheUserlog;          
                
            }
        }

        
    };

});
```

when chatroom3A.html is rendered, the page does not print the data ("usuario") from the form into index.html. I do not know how to indicate the contents to print with "innerHTML", perhaps with the function "responseText". I hope you can help me.

Comment: First: you don't really need localStorage because you can simply store stuff like that in your [flask session](https://flask-session.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). However from a quick glance your code should work in theory, the only problem is that while you're sending the form data with AJAX, you're not stopping the regular submission of the form. First, add the event param: `document.querySelector('#registro').onsubmit = e => {` now you can call `e.preventDefault();` in the next line to stop the submission.

Comment: Also have only one variable `let userlog = localStorage.getItem('userlog') || "";` then have `userlog = document.getElementById('usuario').value;  localStorage.setItem("userlog", userlog);`

Comment: Try `innerText` rather than `innerHTML`. I don't understand why you are storing data in localStorage when there is sessions in flask

Comment: @charchit Likely because they thought to not reload the page

Comment: @ChrisG, I am trying to use localStorage instead of flask session because it does not help me to keep the username after reloading the page. When using e.preventDefault(); the chatroom3A.html page is not rendered and I remain in index.html after submitting the form. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: @mplungjan, I used only the variable "userlog" and adjusted the write line by document.querySelector('#bienvenido'). innerHTML = userlog; but even the username is not printed when rendering chatroom3A.html. Do you think it will be necessary to change the order of code lines or any additional lines?